# fade effect in blackberry (os 4.5 ) application

Tags: blackberry

in my blackberry application i have to create a effect in which fullscreen bitmap is slowly disappearing and ui screen is coming up.

```
protected void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setGlobalAlpha(globalAlpha);//starting value of globalAlpha is 255.
        g.drawBitmap(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), _bitmap, 0, 0);
        g.setGlobalAlpha(255 - globalAlpha);
        globalAlpha--;
        super.paint(g);
    }
```

This code is just for giving demo that what i want.
super.paint(g) is calling 255 times because of that its a poor code.
in one timer task i am calling invalidate();

So any suggestions how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

If you can get away with using 5.0 APIs, you'll save yourself a LOT of work by using the [TransitionContext](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/TransitionContext.html) class.  One of the transition types is "fade".

Comment: yeah i know because of that in question i have specifically mentioned os 4.5

Comment: heh - I must have skipped the title and went straight to the question!

Comment: its OK but i have to stick with os 4.5. i have tried with Display.screenshot(_bitmap) also but on real device its throwing exception.